# Missing libssl3.so when trying to install Flash Debug Player on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, flash

When I try to install Flash Debug Player in Ubuntu 13.10 via the normal means, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo nspluginwrapper -v -i /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so                       
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** ERROR: libssl3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** ERROR: libssl3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so
```

The existing answers for this problem (install ia32-libs) doesn't work of course, because that package hasn't existed since MultiArch was added a versions ago.

What do I need to do to get this working on 13.10?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to install the 32bits libnss3 package:

`sudo apt-get install libnss3:i386`

Comment: Just to help confirm: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libnss3/filelist